# Super + Space as shortcut for layout switching. Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I have installed Linux Mint with Cinnamon recently. I have swapped my <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> keys and now I want to set <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keys to switch between layouts. How can I do that trick?

I've searched this option in
`Settings > Keyboard layouts > Options > Switching to another layout`

Also I've tried to search in dconf editor, but all I found is value `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.switch-input-source` and when I change it to `'<Super>space'` nothing happens.

Comment: Super means Windows key on your keyboard.

Comment: I know that, but when I pressing Win key (Super key) with space nothing happens despite that I've already set '<Super>space' for layout switching in dconf.

Comment: You should disable the existing shortcut first check this post for that:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607728/linux-mint-20-cinnamon-how-to-disable-superspace

Answer (score 2):

I see it under
`System Settings > Keyboard > Layout > Options > Switching to another layout > Win+Space`.

When I check that box, the shortcut works for me and my keyboard layout changes. And I have my <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> keys swapped as well via `Alt/Win key behavior > Alt is swapped with Win`. Both seem to work as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was right under your nose. I'm also used to <kbd>Super (Win)</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Hope this helps:

1. Click on Options... in Keyboard, Layouts

[image]

2. Expands Switching to another layout

[image]

3. Select <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]