# Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon - How to disable [Super][Space]?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I'd like to be able to disable [Super][Space] as the key combination that cycles through "desklets" so I can use it as the shortcut for switching input methods (languages) with IBus (this is IBus' default shortcut).

I opened "Keyboard", clicked the "Shortcuts" panel, and in General, selected "Show Desklets". I double clicked [Super][Space], pressed [Backspace] to delete, but [Super][Space] still cycled through the desklets, even after reboot.

This illustrates that the removal of the shortcut was registered, but Cinnamon seems to ignore it:

```
% dconf dump /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/ 
[/]
show-desklets=@as []
```

What's going on, and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My first time answering, hopefully it is helpful and a functional solution is provided.

So try this:

Right-click anywhere on your panel to bring this menu:
[image: right-click on the panel]

Press the "Panel edit mode". You should see your panel changing its color.

Then you can right-click on any of the applications located on the panel and the following menu should open:
[image: Right-click on grouped applications located on the panel]

On the menu press the "Configure..." option.

You should see in the section "Hot keys" the option "Global Hotkey for cycling through thumbnail menus". There you should change the already assigned option of "Super + space". (In my screenshot is set to print; that's due to the "print screen" I was doing to provide the screenshot.)

I don't know how you can navigate directly to that "Grouped window list" settings window, but if anyone know, that would be a more direct solution I believe.

[image: The grouped window list]

P.S: Also you need to "uncheck" the "Panel edit mode" option after you are done with the changes.

Comment: Superb answer, very clear instructions and helpful graphics. It worked perfectly. Well done, and welcome!

Comment: Very helpful, this functionality is a little obscure though